# SQL query to sum by group and inner join two tables

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, inner-join

I have two tables like so:

[image]

[image]

Each row in both tables is uniquely identified by the columns week and city.
I want to create one table with 5 columns (week, value_a, value_b, value1, value2) and 3 rows (1 row for each week, with the value columns being summed across each city). The final table should look exactly like this:

[image]

sum_a is the sum of value a for each week across all cities, sum_b is the sum of value_b across all cities and so on.

Here is my SQL query:
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.week = table2.week AND
table1.city = table2.city

Comment: You should put exemple data and not images.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sum column relied by join you just need to sum your tables before to avoid repeat data
Considere that if you have a week in your table 1 and not in the table 2 the data will not be shawn in your example

```
SELECT
    A1.week,
    A1.city,
    A1.value1,
    A1.value2,
    A2.value1,
    A2.value2
FROM (
    SELECT
        Week,
        city,
        sum(value1),
        sum(value2)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Week, city
) A1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Week,
        city,
        sum(valueA),
        sum(valueB)
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY Week, city
) A2
    ON a1.week = a2.week AND a1.city = a2.city
```

Answer (score -1):

the below query can give you output as expected:

```
SELECT table1.week, sum(value_a) as sum_a, sum(value_b) as sum_b, sum(value1) as sum_1, sum(value2) as sum_2
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.week = table2.week AND table1.city = table2.city
group by table1.week
```

Query can be validated by checking the link [db<>fiddle<>example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=036faf4be13fec7f305a3e4b71f73d4a)

[image]

Comment: Putting this code will repeat each line on join and give a false result because if you have two lines in table1 and four in table2, that will duplicate data and give a false sum

Comment: Same problem, here is an exemple. Try to just add a line on week3 that not fit the exact number of records of each table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f85fe26ff1364447ee84a432356ad3d6